# App is crashing Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, google-translate, android-strictmode

My app is running perfectly at debug mode but is crashing at release mode, so when i set debuggable to be true i realized that the error is from switch case and one method.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far 
>  at com.example.speakingtranslator.MainActivity.p(:3334)
> at com.example.speakingtranslator.MainActivity$e.onClick(:228)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7043)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(:992)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7016)
> at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:783)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26595)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6758)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
> **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far**

here is my code

```
default:
    if (checkInternetConnection()) {
     getTranslateService();
     result = translate();
    } else {
     result = getResources().getString(R.string.no_connection);
    }
   break;
   editTranslate.setText(result);
```

And here are the methods

```
public void getTranslateService() {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try (InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials)) {

            //Get credentials:
            final GoogleCredentials myCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(is);

            //Set credentials and get translate service:
            TranslateOptions translateOptions = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(myCredentials).build();
            translate = translateOptions.getService();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public String translate() {
        originalText = editText.getText().toString();
        Translation translation = translate.translate(originalText, Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("yo"), Translate.TranslateOption.model("nmt"));
        translatedText = translation.getTranslatedText();

        //Translated text and original text are set to TextViews:
        return translatedText;

    }
```

Here is the full code of OnClickListener of the translate button,i have set of words that i don't want to bother to send them to the server, that's why I'm using switch case to test for them, so if the enterred value is not from the list then it should send the word to the api for translation.

```
trans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String t = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();

        if (t.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Text Value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            editText.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        String result;

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while loading..."); // Setting Message
        progressDialog.setTitle("Translating"); // Setting Title
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); // Progress Dialog Style Spinner
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }}, 2000);

        switch (t) {
            case "i love you":
                result = "Mo nif̣ẹrẹ";
                break;
            case "i want you":
                result = "Mo fẹ̣ ọ";
                break;
            case "good evening":
                result = "Ẹ kaalẹ";
                break;
            case "i like you":
                result = "Mo fẹran rẹ";
                break;
            case "how are you":
                result = "Bawo lo se wa";
                break;
            case "i need your help":
                result = "Mo nilo iranlọwọ re";
                break;
            case "i need money":
                result = "Mo nilo owo";
                break;
            case "i miss you":
                result = "Aro rẹ nsọ mi";
                break;
            case "what is my name":
                result = "Kini orukọ mi";
                break;
            case "i love my husband":
                result = "Mo niifẹ ọkọ mi";
                break;
            case "i am hungry":
                result = "Ebi n pa mi";
                break;
            case "i want hot water":
                result = "Mo fẹ omi gbona";
                break;
            case "look at me":
                result = "Wo mi";
                break;
            case "come back":
                result = "Pada wa";
                break;
            case "it is very good":
                result = "O dara pupọ";
                break;
            case "come to school":
                result = "Wa si ile-iwe";
                break;
            case "help yourself":
                result = "Ran ara rẹ lọwọ";
                break;
            case "wait for me":
                result = "Duro de mi";
                break;
            default:
                if (checkInternetConnection()) {
                    getTranslateService();
                    result = translate();
                } else {
                    result = getResources().getString(R.string.no_connection);
                }
            break;
        }
        editTranslate.setText(result);
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you using` Matcher` to match any regular expression ?

Comment: No, only switch case to determine to given string value

Comment: please add that portion of code

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code of onclickListener of the button that will trigger the translation.

Answer (score 0):

Turn minifyenabled back to **false** has solved the problem.